# SQL crosstab query for numeric attribute

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL query to for cross-tab, to get the count of for each distinct categorical  category for every bin range of continuous attribute.

Eg: Gender (categorical attribute male,female) & Age (continuous attribute ).
For Age , binning create as, 0-10, 10-20, 20-30, 30-40 ...

So I am looking for query to return me count for every range on Categorical attribute(Gender).

Expected Output: for particular range : 0-10

```
CNT          LABEL
365503       MALE
177939       FEMALE
```

The following query are working but for one range at a time , so i have to put a loop for each range ,

```
WITH q0 AS
  (SELECT GENDER label
  FROM IMPORTDATAAJ
  WHERE GENDER IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY GENDER
  ORDER BY 1 ASC
  ) ,
  q1 AS
  (SELECT GENDER label
  FROM IMPORTDATAAJ
  WHERE AGE >= 0
  AND AGE   <= 1.0
  ),
  q3 AS
  (SELECT q0.label label,
    COUNT(q1.label) cnt
  FROM q0
  LEFT OUTER JOIN q1
  ON (q0.label=q1.label)
  GROUP BY q0.label
  ORDER BY label
  )
SELECT q3.label,q3.cnt FROM q3
```

But I want to remove this loop to enhance the performance and want to get all at once for all range.

Answer (score 1):

Use an auxilliar table like this:

```
select (level-1)*10 low_limit, 
        level*10 high_limit ,
        ((level-1)*10) || ' - ' || (level*10) as band
from dual connect by level <= 12
```

And then just join with it and group by:

```
select band, gender, count(*)
from(
    select gender as label
    from IMPORTDATAAJ
    join (select (level-1)*10 low_limit, 
            level*10 high_limit ,
            ((level-1)*10) || ' - ' || (level*10) as band
          from dual connect by level <= 12
          )
    on age >=low_limit and age < high_limit
    )
group by band, gender
order by band, gender;
```

Comment: what is band here ? and I have a range of age (0-10,10-20,20-30..) and i want count for each range seperately as I explained above. The above result in my question is for one range but I am looking for all range at a time instead of looping

Comment: Did you run the auxiliary query? You'll understand then :)